# make if checks only one command

Tags: java, android, button, if-statement

I have a ViewFlipper and a next button and I want the button to stop after checking and doing one  command
I want it to stop checking the rest unless I click on it again

My code:

```
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 0){if(qOne.isChecked()) {CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}} 
            if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 1){if(qTwo.isChecked()){CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}}
            if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 2){if(qThree.isChecked()){CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}}
            if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 3){if(qFour.isChecked()){CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swith statement is ok, but I suggest this way. It's much more readable and you can add objects with less fuss and mess.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    CheckedObject[] objectsToCheck = new CheckedObject[]{qOne,qTwo,qThree,qFour};
    int index = flipp.getDisplayedChild();
    if (objectsToCheck[index].isChecked())
    {
         CorrectToast();
    }
    else 
    {
         WrongToast();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does CheckedObject[] stand for? Android Studio can not resolve it.

Comment: @user2989698 you have to replace CheckedObject with the proper type of qOne, qTwo etc. JCheckBox[] if you are using JCheckBox. I don't know the class of object you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use switch statement instead:

```
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(flipp.getDisplayedChild()) {
            case 0: if(qOne.isChecked()) {CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();} break; 
            case 1: if(qTwo.isChecked()) {CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();} break;
            case 2: if(qThree.isChecked()) {CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();} break;
            case 3: if(qFour.isChecked()) {CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();} break;
            default: break; //do default action,
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `if () else if ()` construct

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if() { } else if() { }` statement for that purpose like this

```
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 0){if(qOne.isChecked()) {CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}} 
            else if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 1){if(qTwo.isChecked()){CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}}
            else if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 2){if(qThree.isChecked()){CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}}
            else if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == 3){if(qFour.isChecked()){CorrectToast();}else{WrongToast();}}
        }
    });
```